# Defining array in php

Tags: php

```
$result[] = array("'../../folder1/insidefolder1'","'../../folder2/insidefolder2'");
define('dirarr', serialize($result));
```

I want to define an array like above. Then I `print_r()` it like below

```
print_r(dirarr);
```

But I am not getting the output I expect. I want to get something like this `["'../../folder1/insidefolder1'","'../../folder2/insidefolder2'"]`

instead I get something like this

> a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:29:"'../../folder1/insidefolder1'";i:1;s:29:"'../../folder2/insidefolder2'";}}
>   Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 219

Comment: Why are you serializing the `array`? Why not simply store it?

Comment: @SougataBose i read it somewhere in SO i forgot the link. It said you need to serialize i think it was wrong

Comment: When you serialize an array , you can't treat it as array , unless you unserialize it

Comment: @guradio check - https://eval.in/612621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define('dirarr', serialize($result));
```

It serializes the array; see the [`serialize()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) for more details.

When you want to use the value, you need to [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it to something like this:

```
$unserializedArray = unserialize(dirarr);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `print_r(dirarr);` you will get a serialized string

You need to unserialize it before using it as an array.

```
$result[] =     array("'../../folder1/insidefolder1'","'../../folder2/insidefolder2'");
define('dirarr', serialize($result));
```

And Later

```
$array = unserialize(dirarr);
print_r($array); // will give you the expected result
```

Answer (score 0):

*serialize* serializes array. Maybe you want json format? So not:

```
define('dirarr', serialize($result));
```

but

```
define('dirarr', json_encode($result));
```

or just

```
define('dirarr', $result);
```

It all depends what you want to do with it later

Answer (score 0):

```
$result[] =array("'../../folder1/insidefolder1'","'../../folder2/insidefolder2'");
print_r($result);
```

Please remove this code. Passing strings from php to javascript only need the serialization.

```
define('dirarr', serialize($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need serialize but `json_encode()` this

```
$result[] = array("'../../folder1/insidefolder1'","'../../folder2/insidefolder2'");
define('dirarr', json_encode($result));
```

With json_encode() you can easily use this array in JavaScript. Serialize works in different way. It's good to pass objects via some kind of communication(like sockets, session, api) and deserialize it to get the same object in different place.